# Sorting the Pandas DataFrame Describe output (early solutions do not work)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to sort the describe of a dataframe, read several helps posts on very similar matter, but I can no make it work.

My three lines of code go like this:

```
df1 = myDataset.groupby(['country_code'])['country_code','score'].describe() 

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):

display(df1) 
display(df1.reset_index()) 
display(df1.reset_index().sort_values('count', ascending=False))
```

First display shows :

```
    score
count   mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max
country_code                                
AE  10.0    10.000000   31.622777   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    100.0
AM  1.0 0.000000    NaN 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    0.0
AO  5.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    0.0
...
```

second display goes:

```
    country_code    score
count   mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max
0   AE  10.0    10.000000   31.622777   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    100.0
1   AM  1.0 0.000000    NaN 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    0.0
2   AO  5.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.00    0.0 0.00    0.0
...
```

and the third raise an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-855a7c54543c> in <module>()
      6       display( df1.reset_index() )
      7 
----> 8       display( df1.reset_index().sort_values('count', ascending=False) )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1561             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1562         else:
-> 1563             raise KeyError(key)
   1564 
   1565         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'count'
```

Not sure what I am doing difrerently than other solutions as:
[Sorting the Pandas DataFrame Describe output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000762/sorting-the-pandas-dataframe-describe-output)

Comment: Linked solution used only one key for ```.describe()```, but you used two keys ```['country_code','score']```. So ```df1.reset_index()``` have multi-column index and ```.sort_values('count', ascending=False)``` can not find key ```'count'```. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733871/multi-index-sorting-in-pandas

Comment: dindnt know about "multi-column index" thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.sort_values([('score','count')], ascending=False)
```

thanks [@ilkyun-im](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10222778/ilkyun-im)